# Ubuntu Server 12.04 can access LAN but not internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

Using Ubuntu Server (12.04) via command line, I can access the LAN (e.g. ping local machines) but not the internet (e.g. "ping google.com" or "sudo apt-get update"). How should I troubleshoot this?

I'll start by saying that I *was* able to access the internet (using sudo apt-get) but after some 'configuration work' I can now only access the LAN. It previously worked when I had a DHCP connection. I noticed the problem some time after I'd switched to a static IP. I've switched back to DHCP but with no luck.

**/etc/network/interfaces** currently looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid myrouterssid
wpa-psk myrouterpassword
```

**ifconfig -a** reports:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:7a:d9:1b:07
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:68ff:fed9:1b07/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:23826 (23.8 KB)  TX bytes:47487 (47.4 KB)
          Interrupt:16

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 86:19:a7:9b:a6:4a
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:94:ea:de:1f:78
          inet addr:192.168.0.3  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:eaff:fede:1f78/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:58008 (58.0 KB)  TX bytes:1852 (1.8 KB)
```

"ping 192.168.0.1" (gateway) works. "ping 192.168.0.100" (self) works. "ping 192.168.0.7" (another PC) works. "ping google.com" reports "ping: unknown host google.com". "ping 173.194.34.72" (google.com) fails.

I can also SSH to this ubuntu server from another PC (although it now waits about 20 seconds before it asks for the password whereas it was previously instantaneous - significant?)

EDIT: **route -n** reports:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Comment: What are your routes for this machine? (hint `route -n`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your resolv.conf entries are probably bad.  You should determine the proper address(es) and write them manually in resolv.conf (removing current entries).
I guess that DNS server is the same as gateway (192.168.0.1).

You can try this before making changes in resolv.conf by command:

```
dig @192.168.0.1 google.com
```

Above command tries to ask 192.168.0.1 (not Your current set in resolv.conf) for google.com IP, if there is working DNS server the answer will contain following text:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.35.162
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.35.161
google.com.             300     IN      A       173.194.35.164
[...]
```

If it fails try entering different IPs in `dig` command

Another problem is that trying to ping google by IP fails (as you wrote).  To make a quick test why it fails try following command:

```
traceroute 173.194.35.162
```

You'll see which one of the hops causes the problem. It's possible that Your gateway is not working.

Comment: Ah, fantastic. You're right it was the gateway that was the problem - there were some legacy filters on the IPs I wanted to use. When I switched to static IP I ended up on those IPs and when I switched back to DHCP the router left my PC on those IPs. Thanks to everyone for really useful answers and great troubleshooting tips. I'll vote up (as soon as I have enough privileges). @daftu thanks for spotting the underlying issue (which wasn't on the PC itself at all).

Comment: Just as a side note, I had this issue too, and the problem was that a computer had stolen the static ip address I had set.

Answer (score 5):

Things to check:

You've got nameservers defined in /etc/resolv.conf

**`/etc/resolv.conf`:**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

You've got a default gateway in your routing table:

**`ip route`**

```
tom.oconnor@charcoal-black:~$ ip route
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.27 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 100
```

Default route is the one that starts "`default via`"

Comment: **/etc/resolv.conf** containst 2 nameservers: `nameserver 194.168.4.100
nameserver 194.168.8.100`. **ip route** reports `default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.101
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.8
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1`

Comment: Your name servers are on .4.100 and .8.100 and your default route is 0.1...but your masks are 255.255.255.0. How would it *see* those DNS servers?

Comment: @Bart You're saying that the masks mean that the nameserver IPs would be unreachable, right? Sorry I don't understand enough to see how these all hook together. Is it possible that as **etc/resolv.conf** is auto-generated perhaps these nameservers appeared here _before_ I started having problems?

Comment: Do you have other machines in the same network that are working, and can you check their DNS server settings and/or mask settings?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your name resolution (DNS) is broken. Check your /etc/resolv.conf and the DNS settings of your network manager.

Comment: I have 2 nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf. How do I check the DNS settings of my network manager (via command line)?

Comment: NB nmcli is not installed and without internet access I can't download & install it.

Comment: Use `dig` or `host`. Host is installed on most systems by default.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your default route. Your DHCP server for WiFi doesn't send information about it. Please, correct you DHCP configuration, or you must set it on the Ubuntu system by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of a bogus IP/MAC binding in your router. Issue the 
`ifconfig` command, check your HWaddr against the router's IP/MAC binding table.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/resolv.conf probably missing nameservers, then restart the network manager service NetworkManager restart.

Comment: I don't see anything new in this answer. The accepted answer has the same suggestion with more detail.